# Jboss SSO session is not destroyed after maxInactiveInterval

Tags: java, session, jboss, single-sign-on, jboss6.x

We have successfully configured SSO in a JBoss EPA 6.4.17 Cluster.

Each user session has been configured with a **maxInactiveInterval** of 1 minute.
So client will keep on sending a alive request to server every 30 seconds to keep the session alive.
I have verified the session in Jboss cache is cleared on manual logout. similarly the close tab and close browser actions are handled properly.

In case, when I kill the browser process or terminate the client connection with server, it is expected to destroy the cache from the server after 1 minute.
since the maxInactiveInterval of session is 1 minute. But its not destroyed as expected.

- On debugging. I found the following

  1. A Jboss thread kept on running to check the sessions validity. ie ContainerBase.ContainerBackgroundProcessor
  2. This thread will check the session validity. if session ideal time is greater than maxInactiveInterval it will expire the session.
  3. By default Jboss session **maxEmptyLife** is 30 minutes. But I override it as 0 minutes using system properties. so the session will
     be destroyed immediately.
  4. Both manual logout and session timeout operations are calling session.invalidate();
  5. Then code control reached function sessionEvent in ClusteredSingleSignOn.java
  6. In this sessionEvent() method (below is Jboss source code),

     ```
     // Was the session destroyed as the result of a timeout or
     // the undeployment of the containing webapp?
     // If so, we'll just remove the expired session from the
     // SSO. If the session was logged out, we'll log out
     // of all sessions associated with the SSO.
     boolean timedOut;
     boolean stopped = false;
     if ((timedOut = isSessionTimedOut(session)) || (stopped = isManagerStopped(session))) {
         WebLogger.WEB_SSO_LOGGER.tracef("remove session %s from SSO %s, isSessionTimedOut=%s, isManagerStopped=%s", session, ssoId, timedOut, stopped);

         removeSession(ssoId, session);

         // Quite poor. We hijack the caller thread (the Tomcat background thread)
         // to do our cleanup of expired sessions
         processExpires();
     } else {
         WebLogger.WEB_SSO_LOGGER.tracef("user logged out of SSO %s", ssoId);
         // The session was logged out.
         logout(ssoId);
     }
     ```

  the control goes to the IF block in session time out and goes to ELSE block in manual logout.

  7. In IF BLOCK the processExpires() is called, which used to destroy already expired sessions from Jboss cache, but do not destroy the current session from Jboss cache.
  8. When the session idealtime is greater than sessions maxInactiveInterval. The control goes to IF block of above code snippet. which results in Jboss cache to hold the session. (but expected to destroy session from Jboss cache)
  9. When I open the browser after 1 hour (which is terminated by killing its process). It prompt me to reload windows with old state. when I press reload. the application get logged in automatically since the browser session is catched in Jboss server. But it is  expected to prompt the login page.

It is a security issue. where I can access the server using curl request like ajax request even after termination the client browser.

Is this an existing issue? or any fix available in Jboss?